# Does Android clean up Activity's member variables when the Activity become stopped

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an `Activity`, where I initialize a class member variable in `onCreate()`. In some case, I need to `startActivity()` which means this `Activity` turn into stopped state. When I come back, I need to use the variable.

This works OK in most phones, but I also get some crash from my users because the member become `null` on their phones. This member just contains some `String` and a `POJO`.

Does Android clean up Activity's member variable to free up memory?

Comment: Are the members local to the onCreate()?

Comment: He described it as a "member variable" which means not local - assuming the description is accurate.  Have you searched for usages of the variable to make sure you're not setting it somewhere else like `onStop` ?

Comment: Sorry for my description. The member belongs to the Activity, not local. And I'm sure that I didn't set the variable after initializing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those member variables will be cleared out if onDestroy is called, even if the activity isn't finished.  You can simulate this by turning on "Don't keep activities alive" in developer settings.  Once that's enabled, start your activity and then pause it (i.e. hit the home button)

To get around this, you'll need to store those member variables in onSaveInstanceState, and then restore them using the savedState bundle in onCreate

Comment: But my activity didn't have onDestroy called， it's just stopped by onStop called. Will those member variables be cleared out when onStop called sometime?

Comment: onDestroy can be called, even if you haven't called through to finish().  This can happen when memory is low or something.  If you turn on the don't keep activities alive setting, you'll see what I mean.     In this situation, you'll see onStop and onSaveInstanceState get called.  If your activity is destroyed while it's paused, onCreate will be called again and the savedState bundle will not be null.